# "[some string] is a required argument that is missing" just won't go away

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm just an amateur making a simple discord bot and have a command here that is 'add' as you can see. The issue is that when I run it it's fine, but when 'mes' is empty, we get the good ol':

"mes is a required argument that is missing.".

The code

```
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, *, mes):
    if not mes == '':
        await ctx.send('Added *' + mes + '* to the list')
        file1 = open('file1.txt', 'a')
        c = mes.lower()
        word = '\n' + c
        file1.writelines(word)
        file1.close()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a word to add")
```

I looked for people with similar problems but all I could find was code that had the 'mes' as required and the fix was *mes which is (ctx, *, mes). I tried many things but to no avail and I have no clue what is wrong here so I could use some help

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is because the argument is required.
To make it optional, make the default value `None`.

```py
@bot.command()
async def add(ctx, *, mes: str = None):
    if not mes:
        await ctx.send('Added *' + mes + '* to the list')
        file1 = open('file1.txt', 'a')
        c = mes.lower()
        word = '\n' + c
        file1.writelines(word)
        file1.close()
    else:
        await ctx.send("Please enter a word to add")
```